# How to manage pip installed packages that require external system dependencies?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, lxml

I have a python app which has a lot of dependencies, all are mentioned in requirement.txt, And many of those packages require non-python stuff to be installed.

lxml needs libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev.
matplotlib needs libpng-dev libfreetype6-dev

I am trying to add a line in ~/.bashrc that executes

source /home/env/activate
pip install -r /home/app/requirements.txt

So that every-time I open terminal I have my virtual environment is setup automatically. But the thing is as these packages need external/ non python dependencies pip always fails. 
How should I tackle this issue so that i get the virtual environment correct?
I am also planning to do similar setup to my teammates' machine, so whenever anything changes in requrements.txt, Nothing else needs to be done.

Comment: https://conda.io/docs/ is done for that. install conda then replace pip install by conda install.